# Can we obtain a derived category from an additive category? Like a category of Banach modules?

Tags: homological-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, derived-categories, banach-algebras, abelian-categories

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra, let **$A$-mod** be the category of left Banach modules (as defined in Helemskii's "Banach and locally convex algebras"), **$A$-mod** is an additive category, but not abelian apparently? (is it never abelian or are there cases where it is?), however, as shown in that book, we can define chain complexes and do homology and cohomology in **$A$-mod**. Let $R$-Mod be the category of $R$-modules, we can build the derived category $D^b(R)$ from $R$-Mod using its category of chain complexes, passing to the homotopy category, localizing, etc.

Can we define some sort of derived category for **$A$-mod** ? Or for any additive category for that matter?

Comment: addressing the more specific question regarding e.g. Ban - you should look for work of Prosmans, Schneiders, and Buehler. (In general I think there is something old in JPAA looking at the "abelian envelope" of a derived category)

Comment: Prosmans and Schneiders point out in their respective work that if you apply their machinery to Ban, what naturally emerges is the abelian category qBan that was introduced by Noel/Waelbroeck

Comment: You can take the derived category of (say right) modules over any sekeletally small additive category. This answers your second question, but it seems to me that your first and second questions are rather unrelated.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Presumably the point is that the OP wants the derived category of A-mod to faithfully encode the Tor, Ext and Hochschild cohomology developed by Helemskii's school. My recollection of reading Schneiders http://www.numdam.org/item?id=MSMF_1999_2_76__R3_0 many years ago is that for this to work it is important that A-mod is what he calls quasi-abelian

Comment: @YemonChoi sure, that's what I meant when I said that both questions seem unrelated to me.

Comment: Thank you both, sorry if that was confusing, and yes Yemon: "**the OP wants the derived category of A-mod to faithfully encode the Tor, Ext and Hochschild cohomology developed by Helemskii's school**", that's exactly what I was looking for, so I was mostly interested in the first question. Just one thing though, when you say "the OP wants the derived category of A-mod...", are you implying that we can indeed build a derived category from A-mod?

Comment: user4464: yes, I think so: this is in Section 1.2 of the Schneiders paper/monograph that I linked to. (It has been many years since I tried to read that paper so I am not as familiar with the details as I once was.) Note that in the paper they consider the category of Banach spaces but not the category of Banach A-modules, however I suspect that the latter category is also quasi-abelian

Comment: Thank you, I'm going over that section right now, it's devoted to the construction of the derived category of a quasi-abelian category, is that the section you're referring to? In section 2.2 it says that if we fix some small topological space the category of presheaves with values in a quasi-abelian category is quasi-abelian, on nlab they define a module as an enriched presheaf, could $A$-mod be a category of presheaves with values in some quasi-abelian category? or is $A$-mod exact? Buhler mentions Banach modules in http://tinyurl.com/qgrrr9z but doesn't straight out say if $A$-mod if exact.